# Javascript function as QML property defined from c++

Tags: javascript, c++, qml, function-pointers, qtquick2

I have the following QML object defined in c++:

```
class MyObj : public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant func MEMBER func)

public slots:
    void callFunc(){
        //Call function pointed by "func" somehow
    }

private:
    QVariant func;
};
```

In QML I use `MyObj` as follows:

```
MyObj{
    func: function test(){ console.log("Hi!"); }

    Button{
        text: "Call func"
        onClicked: parent.callFunc()
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to assign a function to a property of any type other than var.
```

I don't understand, isn't a `QVariant` property supposed to be identical as a `property var`? What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`QJSValue`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html) for this. Qt Quick Controls 2's `SpinBox` [does something similar](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quicktemplates2/qquickspinbox_p.h#n70):

```
Q_PROPERTY(QJSValue textFromValue READ textFromValue WRITE setTextFromValue NOTIFY textFromValueChanged FINAL)
```

Its getters and setters are implemented like this:

```
QJSValue QQuickSpinBox::textFromValue() const
{
    Q_D(const QQuickSpinBox);
    if (!d->textFromValue.isCallable()) {
        QQmlEngine *engine = qmlEngine(this);
        if (engine)
            d->textFromValue = engine->evaluate(QStringLiteral("function(value, locale) { return Number(value).toLocaleString(locale, 'f', 0); }"));
    }
    return d->textFromValue;
}

void QQuickSpinBox::setTextFromValue(const QJSValue &callback)
{
    Q_D(QQuickSpinBox);
    if (!callback.isCallable()) {
        qmlInfo(this) << "textFromValue must be a callable function";
        return;
    }
    d->textFromValue = callback;
    emit textFromValueChanged();
}
```

The getter provides a default function implementation if none was given (or the value isn't actually a function).

The function [is used](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/SpinBox.qml#n67)  to allow the user to return custom text for a given input value:

```
text: control.textFromValue(control.value, control.locale)
```

Taking an example from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html#custom-values), here's how you'd assign/override the function:

```
SpinBox {
    id: spinbox
    from: 0
    value: 110
    to: 100 * 100
    stepSize: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    property int decimals: 2
    property real realValue: value / 100

    validator: DoubleValidator {
        bottom: Math.min(spinbox.from, spinbox.to)
        top:  Math.max(spinbox.from, spinbox.to)
    }

    textFromValue: function(value, locale) {
        return Number(value / 100).toLocaleString(locale, 'f', spinbox.decimals)
    }

    valueFromText: function(text, locale) {
        return Number.fromLocaleString(locale, text) * 100
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I actually had tried `Q_PROPERTY(QJSValue func MEMBER callback)` before asking the question but this somehow gives the error: `invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘QQmlPrivate::QQmlElement<MyObj>’` during compilation. I had then assumed that properties cannot be of `QJSValue` type.